# Socket.SetSocketOption throws invalid argument exception on Mac OS & Linux ,but works fine on Windows

Tags: c#, .net, linux, sockets, .net-core

```
Socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, timeout);
```

If timeout is set to -1, then the method works fine on Windows, but fails on Linux & Mac with the following exception

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (22): Invalid argument at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError
>   error, String callerName) at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel
>   optionLevel, SocketOptionName optionName, Int32 optionValue, Boolean
>   silent) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel
>   optionLevel, SocketOptionName optionName, Int32 optionValue)

If timeout is set to 0 on mac and linux, there is no exception.

1) if timeout is set to -1 it does a indefinite poll on windows. Will timeout=0 do the same on windows?

2) ON linux if timeout is set to 0? Does it do a indefinite poll?

When i use 0 for timeout then the application intermittently fails with

> ```
>     System.NotSupportedException: The BeginWrite method cannot be called >when another write operation is pending.
>       at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, >Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>       at System.Net.Security._SslStream.BeginWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 >offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
> ```

Comment: File a bug with Microsoft. The behavior does not match the documentation.

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. "*The BeginWrite method cannot be called when another write operation is pending.*" - `BeginWrite()` is used for *asynchronous* writes. There can only be one write operation running at a time. That has nothing to do with reading. You have to wait for a write to complete before issuing a new write. Please show your actual code, as you are doing something wrong in it that has nothing to do with `SetSocketOption()`

Answer (score 1):

> 1) if timeout is set to -1 it does a indefinite poll on windows. Will
>   timeout=0 do the same on windows?
>
> 2) ON linux if timeout is set to 0? Does it do a indefinite poll?

Yes, the values of 0 and -1 both have the same behaviour according to the documentation for [Socket.RecieveTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout?view=netframework-4.8)

> The time-out value, in milliseconds. The default value is 0, which
>   indicates an infinite time-out period. Specifying -1 also indicates an
>   infinite time-out period.

Comment: Thank you.But on Windows if the value is set to 0,the application fails intermittently with an exception(something like read and write on the socket cannot be done at the same time) Mine is a multithreaded application. So thought to confirm if 0 & -1 perform the same or not

Comment: @subbaraoc "*on Windows if the value is set to 0,the application fails intermittently with an exception(something like read and write on the socket cannot be done at the same time)*" - that is not a real error, and it is absolutely allowed to read and write at the same time since sockets are bidirectional. What is the "real" error message? You are doing something else wrong in your code, but your did not show your code

Comment: @RemyLebeau I had updated the question with the exception